# Use "or" logic with multiple "if case" statements

Tags: swift, enums, boolean-logic, associated-value

Suppose I have an enum case with an associated value, and two variables of that enum type:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case foo, bar(_ prop: Int)
}

let var1 = MyEnum.foo
let var2 = MyEnum.bar(1)
```

If I want to check if **both** variables match the general case with the associated value, I can do that with a comma:

```
if case .bar = var1, case .bar = var2 {
    print("both are bar")
}
```

But I need to check if **either** matches the case, with something like this:

```
if case .bar = var1 || case .bar = var2 {
    print("at least one is bar")
}
```

However, that doesn't compile. Is there another way to write this to make the logic work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would resort to some sort of `isBar` property on the enum itself, so that the "a or b" test remains readable:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case foo, bar(_ prop: Int)

    var isBar: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .bar: return true
        default: return false
        }
    }
}

let var1 = MyEnum.foo
let var2 = MyEnum.bar(1)

let eitherIsBar = var1.isBar || var2.isBar
```

Comment: I was hoping there'd be a better built-in way of doing it, but it looks like this is probably going to be the cleanest option.

Comment: Why not simply `var isBar: Bool { return self  == .bar }`

Comment: Because that doesn't even compile

Answer (score 11):

My solution for this sort of thing is:

```
if [var1, var2].contains(.bar) {
```

A lot of the time I want it the other way, a single var that might be filtered based on several values:

```
if [.bar, .baz].contains(var)
```

but indeed, if there are associated values involved you have to make them equatable and define an operator.

Answer (score 9):

You have to implement Equatable protocol for your enum:

```
extension MyEnum: Equatable {}
func ==(lhs: MyEnum, rhs: MyEnum) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (let .bar(prop1), let .bar(prop2)):
            return prop1 == prop2
        case (.foo, .foo):
        return true

     default:
         return false
    }
}
```

Then the following code should work:

```
if var1 == .bar(1) || var2 == .bar(1) {
    print("at least one is bar")
}
```

UPD: In case if you don't need to check associated value, you can do pattern matching like this:

```
switch (var1, var2) {
case (.bar, _), (_, .bar): print("at least one is bar")
default: break
}
```

Comment: This won't work well if you don't care about the associated value of `case bar`

Comment: No, it won't work indeed. Updated the answer with a suggestion on how to make it work. Not as nice as `if case` though.

Comment: Yeah, your update with the `switch` statement is the best general solution I could think of also.

Comment: it is not suitable in a lot of cases

Answer (score 5):

My guess would be that `if case` and `guard case` are syntax sugar, and just a small feature supported by compiler to improve developer’s experience. In the first case you are using consecutive conditions, which is also just a language feature to replace `&&` operator to make the code more readable. When you are using `&&` or `||` operators, the compiler would expect to get two expressions that return boolean values. `case .bar = var1` itself is not exactly an expression that could live alone, without some context in Swift, so it is not treat as an expression that returns a bool.

To summarise:

- `if case` and `guard case` are simply syntax sugar, works together with `if <expression>, <expression>` syntax
- `&&` and `||` are just logical operators that are basically a functions that expect two boolean arguments on both sides.

To solve your problem, use the good old switch statement.
Hope it helps.